# DPdensity() with multivariate (3 variables)

Tags: r, dirichlet

for Bayesian Dirichelt process mixture model, I used DP package and DPdensity(). DPdensity() works well for univarate and Bivaraite but not for mulitvaraites.

However, I used data with 3 variables, and  it doesn't give x1,x2 or fun1, fun2, and no dens, but calculates number of clusters.
So seems like it computes and  estimates number of clusters, but I see dens is NULL. So I changed the parameter for prior with three "nu"s like nu1, nu2, nu3. but  still comes with empty x1,x2,  fun1, fun2 and I don't think its a solution

So which parameters I need to change for the function or priors? 
or how i can build x3 or fun3 and get the list for dens? is it can be a solution?
thank you!!!

```
data.scale<-scale(data)
summary(data.scale)


s3<-matrix(c(.25,0,0,0,0.01,0,0,0,0.01), ncol=3)
m3<-c(0,0,0)
psiinv3<- solve(matrix(c(.25,0,0,0,0.01,0,0,0,0.01),ncol=3))
prior <- list(a0=1,b0=1/5,nu1=5,nu2=5,nu3=5,s2=s3,
              m2=m3,psiinv2=psiinv3,tau1=0.01,tau2=1)

# Initial state
state <- NULL
# MCMC parameters
nburn <- 5000
nsave <- 10000
nskip <- 10
ndisplay <- 1000
mcmc <- list(nburn=nburn,nsave=nsave,nskip=nskip,ndisplay=ndisplay)

# Fit the model
#fit.new : with unscaled data
fit.new2 <- DPdensity(y=as.matrix(data.scale,ncol=3),prior=prior,mcmc=mcmc,
                 state=state,status=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)

fit.new2$state$ncluster
```

[Environment outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3vz.png)